# Setting Color Type of TPngImage

Tags: delphi, png

I'm using Delphi's `TPngImage` class to convert BMP images (`TBitmap`) to PNG, by assigning the respective `TBitmap` object with the bitmap image in it, to the freshly created `TPngImage` object.

I need to set the color type to `COLOR_PALETTE` to create an Indexed RGB PNG.

I didn't manage to find any property of the `TPngImage` class that can do it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify color type in the [**CreateBlank**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage.CreateBlank) constructor and instead of assigment simply flush the bitmap on the PNG image canvas. For example:

```
var
  R: TRect;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Png: TPngImage;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('C:\Source.bmp');
    Png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_PALETTE, 8, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
    try
      R := Rect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
      Png.Canvas.CopyRect(R, Bmp.Canvas, R);
      Png.SaveToFile('C:\Target.png');
    finally
      Png.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Dow do I flush the bitmap on the PNG canvas? Thank you again!

Comment: Can you kindly write a code example? Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added an example ;-) It doesn't store alpha channel even though indexed color images can have an additional list of 8-bit alpha values for the palette entries. I'm not sure how to do that with the given class. If you needed even that, ask a separate question about this specific issue, please. But I guess that with the indexed palette you expect losing alpha channel.